# Get data of two different activity in one single activity in android

Tags: android

i have two different linear layouts and both of them have a edit button in it.I want the data of my 1st layout to display in second activity EditText if clicked on edit button in first layout and so for the second.

Comment: Please paste here your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Save the data you need to a file** from any place you want **then read that file** from any place you want!

[How to read and write to a file](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-23%E2%80%93Writing-and-Reading-Files)

**Write a string to a file:**

```
try {
   //use MODE_APPEND to append or MODE_PRIVATE to overwrite the file
   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("NameOfFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   fos.write(("some text to save").getBytes());
   fos.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**Read a string from a file:**

```
try {
   BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("NameOfFile")));
   String inputString;
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

   //only use this while if you've saved more than one line of text
   while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) !=null) {
     sb.append(inputString + "\n");
   }

   mySavedDataString = sb.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Best way to do this is to save it within a file temporarily and read it out again. Delete the file when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

you must try this in third activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

View layout1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout1, null);
EditText tv1=(EditText )layout1 .findviewbyid(R.id.edittext1_id);

 View layout2 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout2, null);
 EditText tv2=(EditText )layout2 .findViewbyid(R.id.edittext2_id);

string tmp=tv1.getText();
tv1.setText=(tv2.getText());
tv2.setText(tmp);
}
```

Comment: of course I guess you want use third activity...if you want do all thing in the two activity that you have, you must use inflate of another layout in each activity...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), you write when it's edited and read when you click the button.

Otherwise pass a variable by [`intent and putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)